# Tuple list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples containing numbers

```
list_numbers = [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

How do I use list comprehension to get a list of the sum of each item in the tuple?

```
expected_result = [7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop through the list and call the `sum()` function on each tuple.

```
sums = [sum(t) for t in list_numbers]
> [7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```